# USB Speakers for Desktop: A Good Idea?

Tags: usb, speakers, usb-audio

I'm not a good at hardware questions and often bought stuff and that seemed useful in the description but turned out to be less than optimal.

Recently, my old PC-Speakers started humming quite audibly when connected to the power, louder than the desktop fans. So I guess it's time to replace.

I browsed shop sites and found that USB speakers are generally cheaper and come without the subwoofer (or whatever the box is called), taking less room and not using up a power socket. But most of the descriptions only mention mobile use and I never had any experience with them.

I'm not an audiophile and just need some basic sound for YouTube, games etc. Is it worth getting myself a pair of USB speakers for my desktop or is that a rather bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how they wouldn't suffice. They are, of course limited by USB's meager power supply. So don't expected too much bass or volume.

I can personally recommend Logitech's Z120 speakers. The need one USB port for power and a standard mini-jack for sound. They really surprised me in terms of sound quality and maximum volume – I expected much worse.